# Pegar o Usuário corrente no MS-Windows

Tags: genexus

Como pegar o usuário logado no windows pelo genexus sem usar código c#:

Ex> Usuario = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

Answer (score 0):

A solucão é usar a função [UserId()](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8518,UserId%20Function). Veja também este sac relacionado com identity impersonation [SAC 11464](https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?pt,,,11464).

Comment: Obrigado. Vou fazer uns testes e depois dou um feeedback